# Will zeppelin 0.6.0 work with Spark 1.4.1?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have installed zeppelin 0.6.0 on my cluster which has spark 1.4.1 (HDP 2.3). As per the [release notes](https://zeppelin.apache.org/releases/zeppelin-release-0.6.0.html) I see that it supports spark 1.6 but not sure if it is backward compatible. 
When I try to run sc.version in the notebook,  I can see that spark job is submitted in yarn but it is failing right away with the following error in application log `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher`

My SPARK_HOME path is correct. So zeroing on the incompatibility issue

```
export MASTER=yarn-client        
export SPARK_YARN_JAR=/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1.2.3.2.0-2950-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/spark-client
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution for this. Zeppelin 0.6 works with Spark 1.4.1. This was happening due to interpreter. The logs zeppelin-zeppelin-servername.log and .out files were helpful to resolve this. I had added highcharts artifact into the spark interpreter and it was not able to find that jar file. After providing correct path, I was able to run highcharts and resolve this issue as well.